# Check if the property of a given object exists or not

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to check if myObj has or not "x" properties. However, is not returning anything when myObj doesn't have the property I'm looking for. Here is the code:

```
var myObj = {
    gift: "pony",
    pet: "kitten",
    bed: "sleigh"
};

function checkObj(checkProp) {

    if(myObj.hasOwnProperty("gift")){
        return myObj[checkProp];
    } else if(myObj.hasOwnProperty("pet")){
        return myObj[checkProp];
    } else if(myObj.hasOwnProperty("bed")){
        return myObj[checkprop];
    } else {
        return "Not Found";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Note: `if (myObj.hasOwnProperty("gift"))` will always enter because `myObj` has the property `gift` so other conditions will never be evaluated.

Don't you wanted to do just this?

```js
var myObj = {
    gift: "pony",
    pet: "kitten",
    bed: "sleigh"
};

function checkObj(checkProp) {

    if (myObj.hasOwnProperty(checkProp)) {
        return myObj[checkProp];
    }
    else {
        return "Not Found";
    }
}

console.log(checkObj("gift"));
console.log(checkObj("foo"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check the property you are passing instead of hardcoding the property in the if clauses.This could then be reduced to a ternary operator.
Because if you have a variable which stores the property, use the [] notation which uses the value of the property to lookup inside your object.

If checkProp  variable is 'gift' then myObj[checkProp] becomes myObj.gift as the value of the the checkProp variable is used.

```
function checkObj(checkProp) {
   return myObj[checkProp]?myObj[checkProp]:"Not found"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)** to get the list of own properties, then invoke **[`Array.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/includes)** to look for the specific property and return it's value.

```js
const myObj = {
    gift: "pony",
    pet: "kitten",
    bed: "sleigh"
};
function checkObj(myObj, key){
  return Object.keys(myObj).includes(key) ? myObj[key] : "Not found";
}
console.log(checkObj(myObj, 'gift'));
console.log(checkObj(myObj, 'pet'));
console.log(checkObj(myObj, 'foo'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) to test if the specified property is in the object:

```js
const myObj = {
    gift: "pony",
    pet: "kitten",
    bed: "sleigh"
};

function getProp(obj, prop) {
  return prop in obj ? obj[prop] : undefined;
}

console.log(getProp(myObj, 'gift'));
console.log(getProp(myObj, 'pet'));
console.log(getProp(myObj, 'bed'));
console.log(getProp(myObj, 'noProp'));
```